# Keep UITableViewCell color when move UITableView rows

Tags: iphone

I have an UITableView, I set the color of the first row as Green.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{   

NSInteger row=[indexPath row];
NSInteger section=[indexPath section];

static NSString *SimpleTableIdentifier1 = @"CellTableIdentifier";

UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: SimpleTableIdentifier1 ];

if  (cell == nil) {

    cell=[[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero//SimpleTableIdentifier1
                                 reuseIdentifier:nil] autorelease];
}            


//------------------------------------------------

if(row==0)
{
            //green color
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.10f  green:0.95f blue:0.1f alpha:1.0f]];

} 

else   //white color
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.90f  green:0.95f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f]];


return cell;
}
```

even if I move the rows, I still hope the first row color is Green, so I set codes as:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {


        [tableview reloadData];



 }
```

but it reports 'Program received signal:  “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”.'

Welcome any comment

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use tableView delegate method

```
- (void)tableView: (UITableView*)tableView   willDisplayCell: (UITableViewCell*)cell forRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

if(row==0)
{
      //green color
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.10f  green:0.95f blue:0.1f alpha:1.0f]];

} 

else
   //white color
    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.90f  green:0.95f blue:1.0f alpha:1.0f]];

}
```